# Initialise static const int with static function

Tags: c++, function, static, constants, init

I have a template class with some integers as arguments. One static const integer (call it `Length`) of this class needs to be calculated based on the arguments. The calculation does need a loop (as far as I know) so a simple expression won't help.

```cpp
static int setLength()
{
    int length = 1;
    while (length <= someTemplateArgument)
    {
        length = length << 1;
    }
    return length;
}
```

The returned length should be used to init `Length`. `Length`is used as a fixed length of an array so I need it to be constant.

Is there a solution for this issue? I know that constexp could help but I can't use C11 or later.

Comment: Of course, you can do some template-metaprogramming to get your constant right. I'm personally not really into the details of that because I think that template-metaprogramming is an atrocity that's best avoided, but it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using metaprogramming. Implementation of C++11 `enable_if` taken from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

template <int length, int arg, typename = void>
struct length_impl
{
    static const int value = length_impl<(length << 1), arg>::value;
};

template <int length, int arg>
struct length_impl<length, arg, typename enable_if<(length > arg)>::type>
{
    static const int value = length ;
};

template <int arg>
struct length_holder
{
    static const int value = length_impl<1, arg>::value;
};

template<int n>
struct constexpr_checker
{
    static const int value = n;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << constexpr_checker< length_holder<20>::value >::value;
}
```

Comment: Hey, that seems to be the correct approach here. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be the correct solution, so +1 for that. Still, it only goes to prove what I said in the comments above: Template metaprogramming *is* an atrocity...